# Automatically apply chattr to new files & directories?

Tags: linux, permissions

I'm planning on applying chattr +a to an existing directory tree.  I'd like to have that bit set for any new files that get written in that directory automagically.  I could run a cron job every minute or so, but that could become problematic.  I suppose I could cobble up something with supervise, but I'd prefer to use a wheel that's already been invented if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this attribute is automatically inherited, but you could use `inotifywait` from the inotify-tools package.

A simple daemon process such as

```
# inotifywait -m -e create -e moved_to . | while read dir action file
do
  if [ -e "$dir$file" ]
  then
    chattr +a "$dir$file"
    echo Added +a to $dir$file
  fi
done
```

Now in another window I did a `touch ff` and this process reported `Added +a to ff`.  An lsattr now shows:

```
% lsattr ff
-----a-------e-- ff
```